# Animate Koch curve generation and include a transition effect

Tags: graphics, animation, fractals

Recently, I saw two kinds of animation of Koch curve iteration generation.

[image]
[image]

I don't know how to make this effect, now I can only do this

[image]

```
Clear[koch];
koch[{A_, B_}] := 
  Partition[
    {A, (2 A + B)/3, (A + B)/2 + Cross[B - A]/(2 Sqrt[3]),(A + 2 B)/3, B}, 
    2, 1];
Manipulate[
  Graphics[Line /@ Nest[Join @@ koch /@ # &, N @ {{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}}, n]], 
  {n, 1, 4, 1}]
```

Question: How to make animation with transition effect like that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Isn't the fastest but there is not much to see for higher iterations anyway. Let me know if anything is unclear.

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[
    Line[
      {#, #2, Dynamic[.5 (#5 + #) + (t + 1 - n) (#3 - .5 (# + #5))], #4, #5}
    ] & @@@ Partition[KochCurve[n][[1]], 5, 4]
  , PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, .3}}
  , ImageSize -> 500
 ],
 {{n, 1}, None},
 {t, 0, 5, .1, TrackingFunction :> ((t = #; n = Ceiling[t]) &)}
]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{
   Opacity@.5,
   Line[
      {{#, #2, Dynamic@RotationTransform[-Pi/3. (n - t), #2][#3]},
       {#5, #4, Dynamic@RotationTransform[Pi/3. (n - t), #4][#3]}
      }          
      ] & @@@ Partition[KochCurve[n][[1]], 5, 4]
   }, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, .3}}, ImageSize -> 500], {{n, 1}, 
  None}, {t, 0, 5, .1, 
  TrackingFunction :> ((t = #; n = Ceiling[t]) &)}]
```

[image]